# さくらのレンタルサーバーにSSHでログインして残り容量を確認する方法

Tags: linux

さくらのレンタルサーバーのスタンダードプランを契約してて、SSHでログイン後にディスク残量を調べようと`df -h`すると以下のように共用サーバーなので全容量の残りしか表示されなかったんですが、

```
% df -h
Filesystem      Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/vtbd0p2      2G    238M    1.6G    13%    /
devfs           1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/vtbd0p4    3.9G    1.6G      2G    44%    /usr
/dev/vtbd0p5     19G    1.9G     16G    10%    /var
/dev/vtbd1        2T    149G    1.7T     8%    /home
```

コマンドライン上から自分が使える残り容量を確認する方法はありますか？

もちろんコントロールパネルにログインして確認すればわかるんですが、コマンドライン上から確認できると便利なので方法があるなら知りたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quotaコマンドはどうでしょう? `quota -h` とか。

Comment: おお、できました！ ちゃんと現在の使用量と最大使用量が表示されてまさに欲しかったコマンドです。ありがとうございました。